# How to choose dialer app in iOS Ionic app?

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework, sip

I am currently working on an ionic app for iOS and I am facing a problem.
I want to make a call via a SIP client. The thing is iOS doesn't let me choose which app to use for the call, it just uses the native dialer.
My question is: is there any way to make iOS ask me which app to choose?
The code I currently use is:

```
window.open('tel:' + nr);
```

I also tried:

```
window.open('tel:' + nr, '_system');
```

Comment: You need to identify the urlscheme that your desired app uses and specifically open that URL. On iOS tel: URLs always make a cellular call.

Comment: I think you're right, but that's not gonna be easy. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Call Number](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/call-number) native plugin.

#### Installation :

```sh
ionic cordova plugin add call-number
npm install @ionic-native/call-number
```

#### Usage :

```js
import { CallNumber } from '@ionic-native/call-number/ngx';

constructor(private callNumber: CallNumber) { }

...


this.callNumber.callNumber("18001010101", false) // Set to false to allow user to choose app
  .then(res => console.log('Launched dialer!', res))
  .catch(err => console.log('Error launching dialer', err));
```

`callNumber()` takes two parameters :

- `number`: String; phone number to call (e.g. "1234567890")
- `bypassAppChooser`: boolean; true if you always wish to bypass the app chooser if user has multiple applications installed that can handle calls

Comment: It should work, but it does exactly the same as the code in my main post.

Comment: That probably means that your SIP client is not recognized as an app that can handle calls. Do you manage to use it from another app?

Comment: Haven't tried that yet, but it's recognised on Android. The funny thing is that once the call is launched(and imediatelly rejected), in the call history of iOS it appears as it was made from my SIP client and if I press on it, it actually opens the app and makes the call from there. Got no idea how that works ..

Comment: I'm sorry I cannot help you with this... Good luck